# Html.Encode does not work atleast not as i think it should

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In asp.net mvc 2 view i am trying to render something if true.

In code below i am trying to use Html.Encode(x) to render value into page but it does render nothing. What is wrong with if statement with html.encode?

Works

```
<%if (!ViewData.ContainsKey("DisplayQtyPrice")) {%>
    <%: entry.Amount %>
  <%}%>
```

Does not work

```
<%if (!ViewData.ContainsKey("DisplayQtyPrice")) {
    Html.Encode(entry.Amount);
  }%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually adding anything to the response stream.  There's nothing wrong with Html.Encode, but you need to do something like this:

```
<%if (!ViewData.ContainsKey("DisplayQtyPrice")) {
    Response.Write(Html.Encode(entry.Amount));
}%>
```

EDIT:  That said, I think your first version is better, unless you have a problem with angle brackets :)

Comment: angle brackets no problem, it's just thorny ugly looking, can't show code to kid's otherwise i loose my rights to complain about their handwriting :)

Comment: Just to clarify the above answer: <%= expression %> is a shorthand for exactly Response.Write(expression)

Answer (score 4):

You are calling Html.Encode in a code block, but that does not mean the result is being written to the Output stream. Try:

```
<%if (!ViewData.ContainsKey("DisplayQtyPrice")) {%>
    <%= Html.Encode(entry.Amount) %>
<%}%>
```

Or shorter

```
<%= ViewData.ContainsKey("DisplayQtyPrice") ? null : Html.Encode(entry.Amount) %>
```

Comment: I think <%: entry.Amount %> is same as what you suggested in first block of code, and yes that's correct way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2008 and/or .NET 3.5 you must encode your output like this :

> 

Having to do this is everywhere is a drag the .NET developers thankfully simplified ensuring your HTML safety in .NET 4 by removing this need entirely with the syntax :

> 

It's merely a usability improvement; read [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/04/10/lt-gt-htmlencode-ihtmlstring-and-mvchtmlstring.aspx) for full Jedi credit :